# Regular Expression for hemoglobin genes

Tags: r, regex, bioinformatics, seurat

I'm quite new to R, seurat and scRNA seq analysis. Using the seurat package in R to analyse single-cell RNA sequencing data, I came across the option to analyse the percentage of hemoglobin-genes per cell. The code suggested in different tutorials is something like
`seurat_object[["percent.hb"]] <- PercentageFeatureSet(seurat_object, assay = "RNA", pattern = "^HB[^(P)]")`

`str_view(rownames(seurat_object), pattern = "^HB")` gives me

```
[10598] │ <HB>EGF
[12625] │ <HB>S1L
[14084] │ <HB>P1
[19108] │ <HB>B
[19109] │ <HB>D
[19111] │ <HB>G1
[19112] │ <HB>G2
[19114] │ <HB>E1
[26440] │ <HB>Z
[26441] │ <HB>M
[26442] │ <HB>A2
[26443] │ <HB>A1
[26444] │ <HB>Q1
```

My impression is that the pattern (`"^HB[^(P)]"`) includes other genes that are not hemoglobin/red blood cell - related, specifically `HBEGF` and `HBS1L` whilst it excludes `HBP1`, which I guess is correct.

I am trying to find a regular expression that excludes the first 3 genes (HBEGF, HBS1L and HBP1), but keeps all the other genes. I have tried patterns like `"^HB[^(P|EG|S)]"` and `"^HB[^(P|S)]([^G])"` and `"^HB[^(P|S)](|[^G])"`.

I'm a bit stuck here, maybe somebody can help me. Thank you a lot in advance!

edit: changed "hemoglob**ul**in" to the correct name "hemoglobin" - apparently I am reading too much about antibodies (aka immunoglob**ul**ins)...

Comment: Rather than using a regular expression I would recommend doing an explicit check against a list of curated HB genes (either hard-coded or, ideally, loaded from a known source). — Both for long-term maintainability, (confidence in) correctness, as well as basic readability.

Comment: That's a good and reasonable thought. Thank you, will do! I just found a regular expression pattern for my problem "^HB[^(P|S)]($|[^G])", in case this helps anyone.

Comment: @KriBaLin That regex might work differently from what you expect. You can use a lookahead for simplicity: [`^HB(?!EGF|S1L|P1).+`](https://regex101.com/r/XFE3Bf/2). I'm not posting this as an answer since I don't know bioinformatics, nor am I too sure about your true intentions and possible inputs.

Comment: @InSync this is great, I didn't know regex101.com thank you :)